# Correlation function calculation

Tags: statistical-mechanics, field-theory, correlation-functions, mean-field-theory

From Mehran Kardar's *Statistical Physics of Fields* page 38 section 3.2

> [...] $I_d(x,\xi)$ is the solution to the following differential equation 
>   $ \nabla^2 I_d(x) = \delta^d(x)+ I_d(x)/\xi^2$
>   The solution is spherically symmetric, satisfying
>   $\frac{d^2I_d}{dx^2 }+ \frac{(d-1)}{dx}\frac{I_d}{dx} = I_d/\xi^2 + \delta^d(x) $
>   We can try out a solution that decays exponentially at large distances as 
>   $I_d(x) \propto \frac{e^{-x/\xi}}{x^p}$
>   We have anticipated the presence of a subleading power law [...]

Here $x,q \in R^d$ and $ I_d $ denotes the correlation

What is the reason for choosing a trial solution like this especially the subleading power law ?

Comment: Can you write down the correct ODE? What you have does not make sense. There is a typo somewhere.

Comment: @mikestone Thanks for pointing out. I have corrected it.